# python efficient substring search

Tags: python, c, performance, algorithm, substring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is string.find implemented in CPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681649/how-is-string-find-implemented-in-cpython)

I have read many posts here in stack-overflow comparing the performance of sub-string search (e.g. [Python string search efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963236/python-string-search-efficiency),
[Is this the most efficient way to search for a substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164711/is-this-the-most-efficient-way-to-search-for-a-substring),
[substring in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154247/substring-in-python), etc...)

I have also looked at the source code implementation of contains [abstract.c](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3d4d52e47431/Objects/abstract.c#l2377).

As far as i see the built-in implementation is an iterative one : [python docs](http://docs.python.org/c-api/typeobj.html#PySequenceMethods.sq_contains)

Does python have an implementation of more sufficient techniques for finding a substring: [Boyer–Moore Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm),
[Rabin–Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm), etc...
???

**EDIT**

The question has been extended:
[Python: Improving sub-string search by embedding sophisticated algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12258847/python-2-7-improving-sub-string-search-by-using-sophisticated-algorithms).

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681649/how-is-string-find-implemented-in-cpython

Comment: +1 it will be interesting to compare it to Rabin-Karp

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: notice that i have asked this question before you have added the link to string_contains.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: It seems that for python 2.7 fastsearch doesn't implement Boyer–Moore (http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2370e331241b/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#l37), am i wrong???

Comment: Better make that a new question, not change the premise of the old one that's already been answered. :-)

Comment: Also note that the tip version of fastsearch.h is not that much different from the 2.7 version; adjustments have been made for [PEP 393](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-393-flexible-string-representation) (unicode strings now switch between 1, 2 and 4 bytes variants) but it's the same basic fast search devised for python 2.5, as described in the effbot.org link.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The actual cpython string search implementation is here:

http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h

It appears to use Boyer-Moore.

Comment: Thanks, i will accept this answer, although i am interested if there is such implementation also for Rabin Karp.

Comment: See the comment on the other answer, it's not B-M, it's inspired (simplified) by B-M with some Horspool and Sunday thrown in. See http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm.

Answer (score 1):

The core implementation does not provide this level of functionality.

You will find implementations for Boyer-Moore or Rabin-Karp for Python using Google.

Comment: While strictly speaking CPython doesn't use BMRK it can provide a sublinear performance (good thing) using algorithm based on BM: [The stringlib Library](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm)