# Searching for string in massive files efficiently

Tags: python, search, optimization, large-files

I found variants of this idea, but none that could get me (very new to python) to where I need to be.

Here is the scenario:

1. I have one massive, 27 gig `hashfile.txt` consisting of unique strings all on separate lines.
2. I need to parse this file line by line searching for a match in another, not-so-large (~800mb) `addresses.txt` file
3. When a match is found, this needs to be written to `outfile.txt`

My current code has been optimized to the best of my ability, but only gets around 150 lines/second. Considering I have over 1.5 billion lines in my `hashfile.txt`, any optimization would help.

```
fin = 'hashed.txt'
nonzeros = open('addrOnly.txt', 'r')
fout = open('hits.txt', 'w')
lines = nonzeros.read()
i = 0
count = 0

with open(fin, 'r') as f:
    for privkey in f:
            address = privkey.split(", ")[0]
            if address in lines:
                    fout.write(privkey)
            i = i+1
            if i%100 == 0:
                    count = count + 100
                    print "Passed: " + str(count)
```

Comment: What's your current code? What do these files look like?

Comment: In particular, could you describe your current algorithm?

Comment: Compiled languages are ~10 times faster than interpreted languages such as Python; Java has a bunch of good built-in libraries you could use.

Comment: @tor: Presumably this will be an IO-bound problem (though this will depend on the choice of algorithm), so the particular language used is unlikely to have as much of an impact in this case.

Comment: @tor That's an extreme generalization. Keep in mind that many string functions things like `str.find()` are implemented in C (in CPython) and are *very* fast. One python mock-up of a utility I did was actually beating my C implementation by about 10% before I compiled with `-O3`.

Comment: Current code added (it's ugly!)

Comment: Not sure of its performance, but on *nix OS you could do `comm -1 -2 hashfile.txt addresses.txt > outfile.txt`

Comment: Don't use a list for lookups, use something with O(1) time complexity, like a dictionary.  `lines = dict.fromkeys(nonzeros.read().split("\n"), 1)`.  **EDIT** Don't use a giant string for lookups either.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thanks, I learned something new today!

Comment: @sberry That change alone increased the speed by several orders of magnitude, nice!

Comment: In addition to @sberry's suggestion, you can get the address as `address = privkey[:privkey.find(',')]` assuming that there is a comma on each line. It won't be anywhere near as big of a speed-up as using a dict instead of a list (btw, you may as well use a set), but it should speed things up. How much depends on how many commas are in each line and how long the parts of each line are.

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking to implement is probably the [Rabin-Karp string search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm). It's highly efficient when you're searching for multiple strings simultaneously in some corpus.

More information about python implementations in this post. [python efficient substring search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244754/python-efficient-substring-search)

Since you're searching for multiple address at once, you would probably want to hash the entries in `addresses.txt` and compare them against the Rabin-Karp hash all at once, for each iteration. Read up more about the rolling hash in Rabin-Karp and you'll see how this works.

Since Rabin-Karp requires all patterns to be the same length; in practice all the addresses are probably of some non-negligible length, you can truncate them all down to the same (not too short) length and use the prefix to hash. Also, you might want to modify the Rabin-Karp hash to be invariant to whitespace and small differences in how addresses are formatted, and also define a custom string comparator similarly that will confirm matches.

Comment: I suspect 27GB of search strings, even if hashed, are unlikely to fit in memory.

Comment: @davidg `addresses.txt` is 800MB, per the OP.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart responded before I could :)

Comment: @sberry suggested a change that is a great short-term fix so I can go to bed, but this is the sort of in-depth answer that will lead me to learn many new things - thank you!

Comment: I don't think you can apply vanilla rabin-karp when searching for strings of different length. There probably are some clever ways to get around this problem though, but that seems like a nontrivial problem.

Comment: Since all the addresses are probably of some non-negligible length, you can truncate them all down to the same (not too short) length and use the prefix to hash. Not a huge issue.

Comment: Hmm yes should work as long as the length of the shortest address isn't too short.

Comment: Comparing short strings isn't the problem, it's the long ones that make things slow. I would truncate down to a certain length and just compare really short addresses directly.

Answer (score 6):

With data sizes like this, I'd use a proper database. Databases are optimized for fast handling of large datasets much better than a Python program one might write.

Direct string comparisons are expensive. Let's hash the strings so that the full *binary tree index* of hashes had a very good chance to fit in memory. md5 is 128 bit and is very fast to compute.

First, computre md5 for each record in either file, and store them in another text file:

```
from hashlib import md5
with open('hashfile.txt') as input:
  with open('hashfile-md5.txt', 'w') as output:
    for line in input:
      value = line.rstrip() # cut '\n'
      output.write(value)
      output.write('\t') # let our file be tab-separated
      output.write(int(value).hexdigest(), 16)) # md5 as long number
      output.write('\n')
```

Repeat the same for `address.txt`, generating `address-md5.txt`.

Take Postgresql, mysql, or even SQLite (I'll use it here), and create two tables and one index.

```
$ sqlite3 matching-db.sqlite

create table hashfile (
  txt varchar(64), -- adjust size to line lengths of hashfile.txt
  hash number(38) -- enough to contain 128-bit hash
);

create table address (
  txt varchar(64), -- adjust size to line lengths of address.txt
  hash number(38) -- enough to contain 128-bit hash
);
```

Now load our data. Native database import is usually much faster than doing inserts from Python via dbapi.

```
.separator \t
.import hashfile-md5.txt hashfile
.import address-md5.txt address
```

Now we can create an index:

```
create index x_address_hash on address(hash);
```

This is a `select` statement that will efficiently scan the large `hashfile` table and look up matching hashes form the small `address` table. The index will be in RAM the whole time (hopefully), as will be most of the address table.

```
select h.txt
from hashfile h, address a
where h.hash = a.hash and h.txt = a.txt;
```

The idea is that index `x_address_hash` will be used to efficiently match hashes, and if hashes match, actual text values will be compared, too.

I did not try it on 29 MB of data, but on toy 2-row example it worked :)

Comment: It's been years since I asked this, but it's a very thorough and great answer. Thanks for taking the time to write it up; I'm looping back on the original problem I was working on here and plan to implement this with a relational database of some sort.